# HTML/Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I've been banging my head against a wall for a day now trying to figure out some simple tab manipulation. I have 3 tabs, each containing different pieces of a form. I need to disable the 2nd and 3rd while the user is on the first. Then when the fill out the first page and click continue and the validation returns true, I can enable the 2nd tab and slide to that. Then when they finish the 2nd page, hit continue, and validation returns true, I can enable the 3rd tab and slide into it. The main thing is I need to disable the tabs until the tab they are currently on is validated. So here's my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
  <li><a href="#information">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#payment">Payment</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="options">
    <form id="frmtype1" action="" name="frmtype1" method="post">
        <header>Registration Options</header>
        <br/>
        <label for="Reg_type1" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type1" value="1"/>
        Registering myself with credit card or bank account
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="Reg_type2" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type2" value="2"/>
        Registering multiple people using credit card or bank account
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="Reg_type3" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type3" value="3"/>
        Registering using a purchase order
        </label>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Continue</button><span class="help-inline" style="display:none;">Please choose an option</span>
        </div>
    </form>             
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="information">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="payment">...</div>
</div>
```

And then my jquery:

```
var val1 = $('#frmtype1').validate({
$('#myTab a[href="#information"]').tab('disabled'); //i have no idea how to prevent the user from navigating here so I just put disabled. Didn't work obviously
$('#myTab a[href="#payment"]').tab('disabled');
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}, //this is to prevent the standard error message from showing, rather you use the inline-text
    rules: {
        'Reg_type': {
            required: true
        }
    }
});

$('#frmtype1').submit(function(e) {
    /*This will validate the first page, if the user didn't select an option then it will display
    the inline text as an error message*/
    if(val1.form()) {
        $('.help-inline').hide();

    } else {
        $('.help-inline').show();
        return false;
    }
});

$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

So first things first, how do I disable the succeeding tabs until the current tab's form is validated to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [default tabs from Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), my approach would be to activate the tab plugin only when needed (because a tab is actually disabled unless you activate it) :

```js
function activateTab(selector) {
    $(selector).on('click.twbstab',function() { $(this).tab('show'); })
        .closest('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
}

activateTab('#myTab a:first');
```

And then you can use your validation process to activate the tabs.

Check the [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nZaLY/). I used an additional class to show that a tab is disabled.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="disabled active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.nav-tabs li.disabled { color: grey; }
.nav-tabs li.disabled a:hover { border-color: transparent; }
```

You could also disable a tab after activation by using something like that :

```js
function deactivateTab(selector) {
    $(selector).off('click.twbstab')
        .closest('li').addClass('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI tabs certainly lets you add tabs dynamically - see demo **[here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation)**

The key lines of code are :

```
tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( ... );//adds a new tab
tabs.append( ... );//append content top be selected by the new tab
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );//updates the internals and the screen
```

I'm sure other tabs plugins offer the same or similar.

Another option is [EasyTabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#collapsible-tab2), which allows tabs to be "cancelable" (see "Collapsible and cancelable" demo near bottom of page) - ie. they are only selectable if some condition is met (a confirm dialog in the demo but potentially anything you like). This may be simpler and more desirable than dynamically adding tabs.